# I don't have "much more" or "much else" to say

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

I am a project manager working in English. I pretty much always close my meetings saying:

> Okay everyone, **I don't have much else to say**; if anybody has a comment or a question feel free to speak now, otherwise I propose we close this meeting.

I wonder if that is the correct way to say that, or if someone has a better / more correct phrasing for this line.

Comment: It's fine, but you need to be aware that requests to improve the phrasing of something are off-topic for this site.

Comment: We say: adjourn this meeting, not close it.  much else is not exactly the same as much more.

Comment: @Lambie - I suppose it's just polite understatement, but doesn't 'not much else to say' mean 'a small amount more to say'? It's the sort of thing that I notice.

Comment: It's fine. Nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can say this (not an exhaustive list):

> I don't have much else to say.
>
> I don't have much more to say.
>
> I don't have anything to add.
>
> I don't have anything else.
>
> I don't have anything more to say.
>
> I don't have anything more to add.

They all mean the same thing. While these might not technically be idioms, they function similarly, so you shouldn't take them too literally. There is no difference between **much more**, **much else**, **anything more**, **anything else**, etc.